# How to add a legend to this histogram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, legend, seaborn

I created a histogram:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
% matplotlib inline

#import csv
df = pd.read_csv('tmdb-movies.csv')

df_star_wars = df[df['original_title'].str.contains("Star Wars", na=False)]
df_star_trek = df[df['original_title'].str.contains("Star Trek", na=False)]

avg_starwars = df_star_wars ['vote_average'].hist(figsize = (8,8))
avg_startrek = df_star_trek ['vote_average'].hist(figsize = (8,8))
plt.xlabel("Bins_Vote", fontsize=16) 
plt.ylabel("Vote_AVG", fontsize=16)
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)  
plt.yticks(fontsize=14) 
avg_starwars.legend()
avg_startrek.legend()
```

My problem is last two rows: I want to add a legend, but it doesn't work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Neither do we know what your csv file contains nor what you want to see in the legend. [SO is not clairvoyants anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - there is not even a hint in the code, what the labels should be. And we can only guess, what the histogram is supposed to show.

Comment: Sorry, it is my mistake:

Comment: My csv file contains data about movies. I focus on start_trek and star_wars. I have different columns like budget_film, revenue_film, vote_average, original_title etc. In my legend I want to see: Star_wars and star_trek --> only two colors; The histogram the bins of voting (like rating 4, 5,6 etc.) and a number of people who voted.